# Have no internet with certains routers

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet, ping

I'm having problems trying to connect to internet with my Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried with different routers (my house, office, my phone as a sharing point, ...) wireless and with ethernet. With some of them it works fine, I can use internet. However, some of them doesn't allow me to use internet. If I try ping 8.8.8.8 it works fine but when it comes to use Mozilla or any browser it has no connection. The icon that can be seen in these cases is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Flb.png)

The point is that with certain routers I have no problem.

Thank you.

Comment: In principle it is up to the owner of the network to configure it and decides to whom it gives permissions. On Ubuntu side, the NetworkManager asks the network for configuration and adds it to the system. But It can not overwrite the permissions on the router.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I've noticed that some applications like Telegram Desktop can send and recieve messages even having the ? icon on wifi. Besides, ping doesn't work always.

Comment: I've noticed that this only happens with vodafone routers.